# Validate html.editorfor

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to figure out a way to validate the user data entered:

View:

```
  <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.CompleteWorkSample.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CompleteWorkSample.EmailAddress)
        </div>
```

This is in MVC3, VB.net.  I'm looking for an easy way to validate a users input data into the editorfor field.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not Validate it in the Action method on your form post ?

```
public Action Result Post(YourViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
          //This is valid
   }
   return View(model);
}
```

Assuming you have decorated your properties with DataAnnotation attirbute

```
public class CompleteWorkSample 
{
  [Required]
  public string EmailAdress { set;get;}
}
```

Sorry this is C#. I am not a VB.NET Guy.